# Scaling the data in a decision tree changed my results?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I know that a decision tree doesn't get affected by scaling the data but when I scale the data within my decision tree it gives me a bad performance (bad recall, precision and accuracy)

But when I don't scale all the performance metrics the decision tree gives me an amazing result. How can this be?

Note: I use GridSearchCV but I don't think that the cross validation is the reason for my problem. Here is my code:

```
scaled = MinMaxScaler()

pca = PCA()

bestK = SelectKBest()

combined_transformers = FeatureUnion([ ("scale",scaled),("best", bestK),         
("pca", pca)])

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight= "balanced")

pipeline = Pipeline([("features", combined_transformers), ("tree", clf)])

param_grid = dict(features__pca__n_components=[1, 2,3],
      features__best__k=[1, 2,3],
      tree__min_samples_split=[4,5],
      tree__max_depth= [4,5],
     )

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid,scoring='f1')
grid_search.fit(features,labels)
```

With the scale function MinMaxScaler() my performance is:

```
f1 =  0.837209302326
recall =  1.0
precision =  0.72
accuracy =  0.948148148148
```

But without scaling:

```
f1 =  0.918918918919
recall =  0.944444444444
precision =  0.894736842105
accuracy =  0.977777777778
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with scikit-learn, so excuse me if I misunderstand something.

First of all, does PCA standardize features? If it does not, it will give different results for scaled and non-scaled input.

Second, due to the randomness in splitting the samples, CV may give different results on each run. This will affect the results especially for small sample size. In addition, in case you have small sample size, the results may not be that different after all.

I have the following suggestions:

1. Scaling can be treated as an additional hyperparameter, which can be optimized by CV.
2. Perform an extra CV (called nested CV) or hold-out to estimate performance. This is done by keeping a test set, selecting your model using CV on the training data and then evaluate its performance on the test set (in case of nested CV you do this repeatedly for all folds and average the performance estimates). Of course, your final model should be trained on the whole dataset. In general, you should not use the performance estimate of the CV used for model selection, as it will be overly optimistic.

Comment: why should my final model be trained on the entire data if i already cross-validate it ?second, do you mean i train it on the entire data or only the training data?